# Ternary operator for two conditions

Tags: javascript

**I wrote the basic javascript which take year and check conditions whether it is leap year or not
how can I make ternary operator like that**

```
gYear=prompt("enter the year");
let abc = (yr) => {
  alert((yr / 4 === 0 && !(yr / 100) === 0 )? "leap year" : "not leap year");
};
abc(gYear);
```

Comment: Just don't. Use a regular `if...else...` and write readable and easy to understand code.

Comment: Also note that is not the correct logic for leap years, as years divisible by 400 (e.g. 2000) *are* leap years.

Comment: What value are you expecting `!(yr / 100)` to resolve to?

Comment: *"how can I make ternary operator like that"* - aren't you already using one?

Comment: Your usage of the ternary operator is totally fine. The problem is with the condition you are using.

Comment: this might help.It's c though https://codeforwin.org/2015/06/c-program-to-check-leap-year-using-conditional-operator.html.  But if else solution would be more readable

Comment: `: ? ` this is the ternary operator  that you are using already! now which ternary operator you need in the code? please elaborate more

Comment: If there are multiple conditions then its not ideal to use ternary operator?

Answer (score 1):

I find it's usually best to not even use the ternary operator. Some languages don't even have one:

```js
function isleapYear(year) {
   return year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0;
}

for (let y of [2021, 2020, 2000]) {
   let b = isleapYear(y);
   console.log(b);
}
```

Comment: "Some languages don't even have one" is not an argument to not use it in languages that do have it.